# Счетчик подписчиков

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

Всем привет, у меня есть сайт на вордпресс и нужно написать какой-то скрипт на js/jquery чтобы отображалось число подписчиков в twitter, telergam, medium, discord. Подскажите с чего начать, куда смотреть. у меня очень мало опыта, поэтому буду благодарна за любые подробные подсказки. Гугл особо не дал ответов, возможно не правильно задаю вопросы. Может есть уже готовые решения?

Comment: Гуглишь  `количество подписчиков API twitter, API telergam, API discord` у этих точно есть методы для подсчета подписчиков... У medium вроде нет API точно не в курсе..

Comment: Нашла способ у твиттера без api, но кажется у остальных нет такого?